# understanding Trace listeners

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, trace, system.diagnostics, tracelistener

I've recently just discovered the power of Tracing(no clue why it took this long). The theory and practice wasn't unknown to me just the resources available in .Net for doing so. Traditionally I would just log the parts of my programs that I needed to investigate until I got an answer to any problems or confusion. As of recent this task just doesn't give me enough information and is far too tedious as my application is too big now. There are not a lot of clear resources on much of this so I have a few questions:

1. If I add my own trace listener source to the trace.listeners collection will that trace listener receive the trace information that can be seen in the trace.axd page when tracing is enabled in the web.config of my application?
2. If so how would I go about creating said listener that can receive that input? I've created my own class that implements the trace listener class and I can't seem to get any other input to be logged other than my own? Have I misunderstood something?

If there is another way to log my application line by line without having to place my own logging, that would be very very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but are you aware of DebugView? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx

Comment: I'm aware of debug view. I really want to be able to log and manipulate that kind of information for my users. Think of it as writing my own debugview. Any recommendations on where I could look? I've looked into reading the outputdebugstring but no luck there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I add my own trace listener source to the trace.listeners
>   collection will that trace listener receive the trace information that
>   can be seen in the trace.axd page when tracing is enabled in the
>   web.config of my application?

You will be able to see anything written to Trace. The trace that is written to trace.axd is a bit different from a plain vanilla TraceSource, TraceListener, etc. The biggest difference is that it uses the Trace object, which is the .NET 1.1 way of doing trace. in .NET 2.0 & later, named TraceSources are introduced.

If you register a TraceSwitch, TraceSource and TraceListener in your web config, you can enable listening to any TraceSource that you know the name of, the WCF libraries are an example.

Other places document TraceSource and TraceListener and switches better than I can, e.g. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/12/simple-and-easy-tracing-in-net.html or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228984(v=vs.110).aspx

> If so how would I go about creating said listener that can receive
>   that input? I've created my own class that implements the trace
>   listener class and I can't seem to get any other input to be logged
>   other than my own?

You can start by subclassing the ConsoleLogListener or a TextWriterTraceListener. This library has many tools for dealing with the rough edges of System.Diagnostics Trace.  https://essentialdiagnostics.codeplex.com/

(Because the built in library has rough edges, expect to see a few people tell you to use some other logging library, there are many, but only System.Diagnostics is built in and always available)

> If there is another way to log my application line by line without
>   having to place my own logging, that would be very very helpful.

This requires "code weaving" or Aspect oriented programming, where you use a tool to recompile your application and add things like logging or trace everywhere or where ever a certain attribute is found. PostSharp is one such application.  Memory profiles sort of give you that line by line trace as a byproduct of showing you where your application is spending most of its time.

Comment: This was a very helpful answer MatthewMartin. I appreciate the time and the sources. I've learned quite a bit from this post. I would vote your answer up if I had the reputation requirements. Cheers!